# NOT EXISTS clause in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

Anyone knows how to perform such query in Postgresql?

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabA 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM tabB 
    WHERE tabB.id = tabA.id
)
```

When I execute such query, postgresql complains "`ERROR: Greenplum Database does not yet support that query`."

EDIT: And how about this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabA 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM tabB WHERE tabB.id = tabA.id AND tabB.id2 = tabA.id2
)
```

**EDIT:** 
I tested in postgresql 8.2.15 for the 4 answers provided by @ypercube. Conclusions are:
1) The first does not work in this version of postgresql, as I said above in the question. The error message can be found there too. 
2) For the other three answers, the execution speed is: (3)LEFT JOIN > (4)EXCEPT >> (2)NOT IN. 
Specifically, for queries that have the same syntax, (3)LEFT JOIN takes about 5580ms, (4)EXCEPT takes about 13502ms, and (2)NOT IN takes more than 100000 (In fact I did not wait util it finished). 
**Is there any particular reasons for NOT IN clause to be so slow?** 
Cheng

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.2 is old and no longer supported. There were major changes in how `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` queries work since then. http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: If you want to find the most efficient of the queries, I think you first have to check the indexes you have on the tables. You don't mention the size of the tables but 5 seconds for a query means (99%) either huge tables or lack of indexes. I suggest you add a new question, including the definitions (`CREATE TABLE`) of the two tables, the queries and the execution plans.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are 3 (main) ways to do this kind of query:

1. `NOT EXISTS` correlated subquery
2. `NOT IN` subquery
3. `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL` check:

You found that the first way does work in Greenplum. @Marco and @juergen provided the 2nd way. Here's the 3rd one, it may bypass Greenplum's limitations:

```
SELECT tabA.* 
FROM 
    tabA 
  LEFT JOIN 
    tabB 
      ON  tabB.id = tabA.id 
      AND tabB.id2 = tabA.id2
WHERE tabB.id IS NULL ;
```

This (4th way) also works in Postgres (which supports `EXCEPT` operator):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
WHERE id IN
      ( SELECT id
        FROM a
      EXCEPT
        SELECT id
        FROM b
      ) ;
```

Tested in [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1dbb8/5) (that all 4 work in Postgres).

Comment: No, It doesn't. I think the reason is the filter "tabB.id IS NULL" is applied before LEFT JOIN, not after LEFT JOIN.

Comment: How to implement this query with NOT EXISTS? Can you offer any help?

Comment: As the error say, it is not "yet" supported by Greenplum. No help can be given. Since, the `NOT IN` query works, use that.

Comment: Suppose I have two tables: UserInfo and UserOrder. I want to find users with no orders. This query "SELECT * FROM UserInfo
LEFT JOIN UserOrder ON UserInfo.userid = UserOrder.userid
AND UserOrder.orderid IS NULL" returns all the rows in UserInfo. In my tables there is exact one row in UserOrder and multiple rows for different users in UserInfo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13139/discussion-between-cheng-and-ypercube)

Comment: I tested the four answer in postgresql 8.2.15. The conclusions are list in my question (The "Edit" part). Thank you for sharing this with me and others.

Comment: Perfect, I'm now using NOT EXISTS, which gives most stable results. And `NOT IN` subquery tends to be disasterous slow with low `work_mem` settings (or big tables).

Answer (score 7):

The part of the error you left out could have pointed you in the right direction. I think it said "DETAIL: The query contains a correlated subquery." So you have to rewrite these with joins or non-correlated subqueries.

```
SELECT * FROM tabA WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tabB);
```

As for the second query, try

```
SELECT * FROM tabA WHERE (id, id2) NOT IN (SELECT id, id2 FROM tabB);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so soon. I updated my question. What about the new query?

Comment: Yes, it says "The query contains a correlated subquery". This kind of query is directly supported by mysql. I thought postgresql also supports it.

Comment: postgres does, with a lot more complex stuff, but greenplum doesn't because it has to drop functionality for performance reasons.

Comment: Anyway, "SELECT * FROM tabA WHERE (id, id2) NOT IN (SELECT id, id2 FROM tabB)" Works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM tabA 
WHERE id not in  (SELECT id FROM tabB)
```

Comment: I updated my question, how to perform the updated query in postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

Four Ways to do ----

For this scenario create

Create Table A with name and subject

```
create table a (
name varchar (30),
subject varchar (40)
);
```

Insert Value

```
Insert into a values ('abdul', 'math'), ('mashood','science'), ('rehan','urdu'), ('saqib','art');
```

Create Table B with name and subject

```
create table b(
name varchar(30),
subject varchar(40)
);
```

Insert Value

```
Insert into b values ('abdul', 'math'), ('mashood','hindi'), ('rehan','farsi'), ('saqib','art'),('xyz','math');
```

Select from table A:

| name | subject |
| --- | --- |
| abdul | math |
| mashood | science |
| rehan | urdu |
| saqib | art |

Select from table B:

| name | subject |
| --- | --- |
| abdul | math |
| mashood | hindi |
| rehan | farsi |
| saqib | art |
| xyz | math |

> 1. Not IN

```
select name,subject from b where name not in ( select name from a where a.name=b.name and a.subject=b.subject );
```

| name | subject |
| --- | --- |
| mashood | hindi |
| rehan | farsi |
| xyz | math |

> 2. Not Exists

```
select name,subject from b where not exists ( select name from a where a.name=b.name and a.subject=b.subject );
```

| name | subject |
| --- | --- |
| mashood | hindi |
| rehan | farsi |
| xyz | math |

> 3. Join

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM b left JOIN a 
ON  b.name = a.name
AND b.subject = a.subject
WHERE a.name IS  NULL ;
```

| name | subject |
| --- | --- |
| mashood | hindi |
| rehan | farsi |
| xyz | math |

> 4. Except

```
SELECT bm.* FROM b bm
WHERE subject IN 
( SELECT subject FROM b where name=bm.name
EXCEPT
SELECT subject FROM a where name=bm.name
) ;
```

| name | subject |
| --- | --- |
| mashood | hindi |
| rehan | farsi |
| xyz | math |